# ListPreference without the radio

Tags: android, android-preferences, dialog-preference

I am making the preference screen for my app. Inside the preference screen, I have a ListPreference to “Spread the word” about the app. However, I don't want the radio buttons there. I want the whole dialog seem as if it is a list of things the user can do, and the user would select one option from the menu which will be executed. How do I do it? I am new to Android, coming from iOS background.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

I have this in my pref_settings.xml.

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="pref_key_tell_friends"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_tell_friends" >
    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/spread_the_word"
        android:entryValues="@array/spread_the_word"
        android:key="pref_key_spread"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_spread" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and this the fragment I’m loading in my activity —

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just updated the question with code

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382097/listpreferences-without-any-radio-buttons

Comment: I posted the answer too, if someone else needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preference works just like any button when it is specified as a `Preference` in the XML, instead of a `ListPreference`, or any other type. So, I just added a listener to the preference, and opened an `AlertDialog` in the listener. Here’s the code —

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);

        Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("pref_key_spread");
        myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                     public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                         createListPreferenceDialog();
                         return false;

                     }
                 });
    }

    private void createListPreferenceDialog() {

        Dialog dialog;
        final String[] str = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spread_the_word);
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        b.setTitle("Spread the Word");

        b.setItems(str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position){

                Log.I(“Clicked the AlertDialog", + str[position]);
            }
        });

        dialog = b.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

And here’s the changed XML —

```
 <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_key_tell_friends"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_tell_friends" >
        <Preference
            android:key="pref_key_spread"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_spread" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Thanks @njzk2 for the pointer.